# Gradient registry has no entry for: TfqSimulateState

Tags: quantum-state, tfq

I am trying to calculate and optimize a loss with TFQ and cirq. Using tfq.layers.State()
to work with statevector instead of its observables. But when I try to fit o get its gradient the following error appears:

```
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:            
            y_pred = qnet(x_train, training=True)
            loss = tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy(y_pred, y_train)

gradients = tape.gradient(loss, qnet.trainable_variables)

qnet.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, qnet.trainable_variables))        

gradients
```

**LookupError: gradient registry has no entry for: TfqSimulateState**

tfq.differentiators.ForwardDifference let us to do this but no exist for tfq.layers.State():

```
# Capa que implementa el circuito cuántico
class QuantumStateLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):    
    def __init__(self, qubits, circuit, in_sym, w_sym, name="VQC"):
        super(QuantumStateLayer, self).__init__(name=name)
        self.qubits= qubits
        self.circuit= circuit
        self.in_sym= in_sym
        self.w_sym= w_sym
        
        # Creación de pesos
        W_init = tf.random_uniform_initializer(minval=0.0, maxval=np.pi)  # Inicializador de pesos
        self.W = tf.Variable( initial_value=W_init(shape=(1, len(w_sym)), dtype="float32"), trainable=True, name="W")
        
        # Orden de símbolos
        symbols = [str(symb) for symb in self.w_sym + self.in_sym]
        self.indices = tf.constant([symbols.index(a) for a in sorted(symbols)])
        self.empty_circuit = tfq.convert_to_tensor([cirq.Circuit()])
        self.state_layer= tfq.layers.State()                         
        
        self.differentiator= tfq.differentiators.ForwardDifference()
        

        self.symbols= symbols      
        self.tfq_results= []

    def get_config(self):
        config = {}#super(ScaleLayer, self).get_config()
        config.update({
            "qubits": self.qubits,
            "symbols": self.symbols,
            "circuit": self.circuit,
            "in_sym": self.in_sym,
            "w_sym": self.w_sym,
            "W": self.W,
            "indices": self.indices,
            "empty_circuit": self.empty_circuit,
            "state_layer": self.state_layer,
            "name": self.name
        })
        return config
    
    def get_symbols_values(self, inputs):                     
        batch_dim = tf.gather(tf.shape(inputs), 0)
        tiled_up_circuits = tf.repeat(self.empty_circuit, repeats=batch_dim)
        tiled_up_W = tf.tile(self.W, multiples=[batch_dim, 1])        
        tiled_up_inputs = tf.tile(inputs, multiples=[1, 1])        
        squashed_inputs= tiled_up_inputs        
        joined_vars = tf.concat([tf.cast(tiled_up_W, dtype=tf.float32), tf.cast(squashed_inputs, dtype=tf.float32)], axis=1)
        joined_vars = tf.gather(joined_vars, self.indices, axis=1)
        
        return joined_vars    
    
    @tf.custom_gradient
    def forward(self, inputs):   
        tfq_results= []
        tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)   
        batch_dim = tf.gather(tf.shape(inputs), 0)
        tiled_up_circuits = tf.repeat(self.empty_circuit, repeats=batch_dim)
        tiled_up_W = tf.tile(self.W, multiples=[batch_dim, 1])        
        tiled_up_inputs = tf.tile(inputs, multiples=[1, 1])        
        squashed_inputs= tiled_up_inputs        
        self.joined_vars = tf.concat([tiled_up_W, squashed_inputs], axis=1)
        self.joined_vars = tf.gather(self.joined_vars, self.indices, axis=1)                           
        circuit= tfq.convert_to_tensor([self.circuit])        
        self.circuits= tf.repeat(circuit, repeats=batch_dim)        
        out= tfq_simulate_ops.tfq_simulate_state(self.circuits, self.symbols, self.joined_vars)
        out= tf.abs(out)**2
        out= tf.nn.softmax(out)  
        tfq_results.append(out)      
        
        def gradient(gradients, variables):         
            return (self.differentiator._differentiate_ana(self.circuits, self.symbols,
                                               self.joined_vars,
                                               forward_pass_vals=tfq_results, grad=gradients))
            
        return tfq_results, gradient               
    
        
    def call(self, inputs):
        return(self.forward(inputs))
```

And this is the model:

```
SEED= 1234
random.seed(SEED)
np.random.seed(SEED)
tf.random.set_seed(SEED)

nInputs= x_train.shape[1]

qnet= tf.keras.Sequential()
input_layer = tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(nInputs))
qnet.add(input_layer)
qnet.add( QuantumStateLayer(qubits, completo, in_sym, w_sym) )


lr= 0.003
qnet.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
                  optimizer=tf.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate= lr),
                  metrics=['accuracy'])

qnet.summary()
```

And this is the code for gradients calculation:

```
n_epochs= 100
lostlist=[]
for epoch in range(n_epochs):    
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:                                                     
            y_pred = qnet(x_train)[0]
            loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy(y_pred, y_train))
            lostlist.append(loss)               
            print("loss:", loss)
    
    gradients = tape.gradient(loss, qnet.trainable_variables)
    qnet.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, qnet.trainable_variables))        

gradients
```

And this is the error:

```
 10     gradients = tape.gradient(loss, qnet.trainable_variables)
     11     qnet.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, qnet.trainable_variables))
     12 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/backprop.py in gradient(self, target, sources, output_gradients, unconnected_gradients)
   1079                           for x in nest.flatten(output_gradients)]
   1080 
-> 1081     flat_grad = imperative_grad.imperative_grad(
   1082         self._tape,
   1083         flat_targets,

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/imperative_grad.py in imperative_grad(tape, target, sources, output_gradients, sources_raw, unconnected_gradients)
     65         "Unknown value for unconnected_gradients: %r" % unconnected_gradients)
     66 
---> 67   return pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_TapeGradient(
     68       tape._tape,  # pylint: disable=protected-access
     69       target,

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/custom_gradient.py in actual_grad_fn(*result_grads)
    558     """Custom grad fn wrapper."""
    559     if variables:
--> 560       input_grads, variable_grads = grad_fn(*result_grads, variables=variables)
    561       if len(variable_grads) != len(variables):
    562         raise ValueError("Must return gradient for each variable from "

/tmp/ipykernel_51148/3224640913.py in gradient(gradients, variables)
     70 
     71         def gradient(gradients, variables):
---> 72             return (self.differentiator._differentiate_ana(self.circuits, self.symbols,
     73                                                self.joined_vars,
     74                                                forward_pass_vals=tfq_results, grad=gradients))

TypeError: _differentiate_ana() missing 1 required positional argument: 'pauli_sums'
```

In summary, If I try to define the gradient for tfq.layers.state() I have a lot of problems but with tfq.layers.Expectation() or SampledExpectation()  (all of them using paulis operators for observables) the gradients run ok using tfq.differentiators.
So, Would it be possible for it to work with tfq.layers.state() without the need of define paulisum and just working with statevectors?

thanks!

Comment: Could you include some of your imports and other variables that are defined in the snippet? Would be helpful in recreating the error

Comment: Hi @ryanhill1, I've added more detailed code and explanationns.Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, could you also include how you've defined `qubits`, `completo`, `in_sym`, and `w_sym` from the second code block? And also what you're using for `x_train` / `y_train`? Trying to recreate the error and those are the last pieces I'm missing.